# No Wifi adapter found - Ubuntu20.210 - Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.10

After my upgrade from Ubuntu 20.4 to Groovy Ubuntu 20.10 , My WiFi adaptor still worked (and the card does still work when i boot into the windows partition)... but after messing about with my /usr/bin permission to resolve another issue , my WiFi adapter give the below message. I have tried most online solutions including updating drivers etc. but Still cannot get the WiFi to work.

```
uname -r
5.9.0-050900-generic
```

WiFi apapter not found
[image]

output from lshw -C network

```
  *-network DISABLED        
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 3a
   serial: b8:8a:60:99:1f:33
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.9.0-050900-generic firmware=36.79ff3ccf.0 8000C-36.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:127 memory:e1100000-e1101fff


 rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: The kernel you mention isn't a *groovy* kernel, does your wifi work when you use the Ubuntu *groovy* kernel?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `rfkill list`?

Comment: @Matigo, updated to include the rfkill list

Comment: @guiverc , changing the kernel was one of the things i tried as a solution initially (that's how I ended up with 5.9), what kernel would  you suggest I load?

Comment: Silly question, but have you confirmed that the computer [isn't operating in airplane mode and that the WiFi toggle is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD2DT.png)?

Comment: @Matigo, yes definitely not, i have tried toggling that , also when thats toggled you see a different image of an airplane over the no Wifi Adaptor found

Comment: what exactly did you do with your /usr/bin ?